Mi condicional if no funciona, o mi bucle for o wile no termina de cargar todo
Tengo un problema con una condicional if dentro de un bucle wile.
Exactamente con ésta declaracion: index % N === 0. Hace que la página no termine de cargar nunca.
Edite agregando más código
import {datos} from "../datos/datosVideos.js";
import {listaCategorias} from "../datos/datosNavegacion.js";

const categorias = {};

  listaCategorias.forEach(e => categorias[e.id] = {
    nombre: e.nombre,
    portada: e.portada,
    perfil: e.perfil,
    items: []
  });
  
  datos.forEach(item => {
    categorias.todos.items.push(item);
    categorias[item.tipo.categoria].items.push(item);
  });

function tarjetaIntercalada(e, N) {
    
    const items = e === "todos" ? datos : datos.filter(a => a.tipo.categoria === e);
    const cortos = items.filter(a => a.tipo.claseModal === "corto");
    const normales = items.filter(a => a.tipo.claseModal === "normal");
    const nombreCategoria = listaCategorias.find(categoria => categoria.id === e)?.nombre || "Todos";
    let contenido = '';
    let index = 0;
    
    while(normales.length || cortos.length) {
      
      if(normales.length > 0) {
        const normal = normales.shift();
        contenido += tarjetaYopVideos(normal);
        index++;
      }
      
      if(/* index % N === 0 && */ cortos.length > 0) {
        
        contenido += `<div class="grupoTarjeta-mini-vertical">`;
        contenido += `<h3 class="titulo">Vídeos cortos de ${nombreCategoria}</h3>`;
            
        for(let j = 0; j < 2 && cortos.length > 0; j++) {
          const corto = cortos.shift();
          contenido += tarjetaMiniVertical(corto);
          index++;
        }
        
        contenido += `</div>`;
      }
    }
    
    return contenido;
  };

contenedores = '';

Object.keys(categorias).forEach((id, pos) => {
        
        contenedores += tarjetaIntercalada(id, 2);
        
};

const section = document.createElement("section");
        section.classList.add("paginacion");
        section.setAttribute("id","paginacion");
        section.innerHTML = contenedores;

{datos} y {lista categorías} son archivos .js solamente de arrays
Intenté cambiar algunas órdenes, sacando el index++ del bucle for, pero aún no me funciona.
Lo que hace mi código es: muestra un grupo de 2 tarjetas, cada cierto número de tarjetas normales, tal cual como en la lista de tarjetas de la app de YouTube.
Mi código es extenso, pero si es necesario editare y agregaré más si pudieran ayudar.
Tal como está, no muestra las tarjetas en orden correcta: intercala de uno en uno,
Pero no cada dos, como está definido en el for.

¿Qué representa N y que rango de valores toma?

Edite mi pregunta agregando más código para tener un panorama completo de como está estructurado

El probable error es que el N no es pasado o es igual a 0, de esta forma afecta la operación index % N.
No va a presentar error, pero lo que va a suceder es que el resultado será siempre NaN (/Not a Number/), considerando que cualquier comparación con NaN va a retornar false, y lo que depende de index % N === 0 nunca será ejecutado.
Pero no se trata solo de eso: si N es undefined, la comparación nunca será verdadera y no funcionará.
Lo que puede ayudar es validar el N antes de usar:
 if (!N || N <= 0) {
 
}

*
function tarjetaIntercalada(e, N) {
  if (!N || N <= 0) {
  throw new Error("El N debe ser mayor que 0");
}
  
  const items = e === "todos" ? datos : datos.filter(a => a.tipo.categoria === e);
  const cortos = items.filter(a => a.tipo.claseModal === "corto");
  const normales = items.filter(a => a.tipo.claseModal === "normal");
  const nombreCategoria = listaCategorias.find(categoria => categoria.id === e)?.nombre || "Todos";
...


Gracias. Intenté aplicarle de esta forma pero aún no me funciona. Edite con más código mi pregunta

Tienes 2 arrays:

normal
cortos

Cuando cortos.length > normal.length y cortos.length sea impar se producirá el problema, que te dekará un loop infinito
Dado que:

La condición del whileserá verdadera, ya que cortos tendrá items
No entrará nunca al primer if, ya que normal está vacío
No entrará nunca al segundo if, ya que index % N === 0 no se cumple

Y es que tu while no depende del index, por eso se corre el riesgo de generar un loop infinito;
Tu código debería ser algo como:
//Esta es una función generadora, entregará un iterator 
function* getItem(cat, n) {
  const items = cat === "todos" ? datos : datos.filter(a => a.tipo.categoria === cat);
  const cortos = items.filter(a => a.tipo.clase === "corto");
  const normal = items.filter(a => a.tipo.clase === "normal");
  const nombreCategoria = listaCategorias.find(categoria => categoria.id === cat)?.nombre || "Todos";
 
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length;) {
    if (dato = normal.shift()) yield tarjetaYopVideos(dato), i++; //normal
      
    if (i % n === 0) {
      yield `<div class="grupoTarjeta-mini-vertical">`;
      yield `<h3 class="titulo">Vídeos cortos de ${nombreCategoria}</h3>`;
      for(let j=0; j<2;j++){
          if (corto = cortos.shift())
            yield tarjetaMiniVertical(corto), i++;
          else break;
       }
      yield `</div>`;
    }
  }
}

//juntamos el contenido de la función generadora
//en una única variable
function render(items){
  let contenido="";
  for (let i of items) 
    contenido+= i;
  return contenido;
}

//así cargamos todo el contenido de un tirón
document.getElementById("#un_id").innerHTL = render(getItem("todos",2));


Esto sería una manera diferente de aplicar las funciones ? Edite mi pregunta con más código para ver toda la estructura

@NarcisoAifuz Hola narciso, no entendí a tu pregunta
